# Change output of a model in ORM to my own format of data in ORM - sequilize node

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

Instead of showing the status as Integer, I need the status to be ("Pending", "Active", "InActive").
How can I achieve this in node

`var CustomerLogin = sequelize.define('users', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(4),
      allowNull: false
    },
});`

Comment: Show your [mcve] and give us more details about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Whereever you need to display the status you can use a function like this:

```
function DisplayStatus(status){
  switch(status){

      case 0: 
          return "Pending"
      ...
      default: 
          return "unknown status"

  }
}


....


const status = DisplayStatus(yourStatusInteger)
```

Comment: I need to do this in my ORM Model

Comment: I dont understand the problem. Change the type to string then? You can even make it an enumeration